# How to read a sparse directed graph in scipy

Tags: python, graph, scipy

I have a sparse weighted directed graph represented in a file with each line in the format

> from  to weight

I would like to read it into scipy's compressed sparse format so I can perform simple traversal and graph algorithms on it (or in fact any memory efficient representation).  However, given a node I would like to be able to list all its outgoing edges in order of weight quickly without having to sort them each time.   It's ok to sort each one once of course.

Is it possible to do this in scipy or  using any other python package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load your data with something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sps

data = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', dtype=[('from', np.intp),
                                        ('to', np.intp),
                                        ('weight', np.float)])
```

If you want to store your weights in a sparse matrix `graph`, where `graph[i, j]` is the weight from node `i` to node `j`, you could do:

```
graph = sps.csr_matrix((data['weight'], (data['from'], data['to'])))
```

To have a sorted list of outgoing nodes, I would use a dictionary, where `sorted_to` is an array of outgoing nodes sorted by weight. It's a little hacky, and dependent on the CSR sparse matrix format, but you could do:

```
graph = sps.rand(10, 10, density=0.1, format='csr')
data, indptr, indices = graph.data, graph.indptr, graph.indices
non_empty_rows, = np.nonzero(np.diff(graph.indptr))
sorted_out = {}
for j in non_empty_rows:
    weight_slice = data[indptr[j]:indptr[j+1]]
    out_slice = indices[indptr[j]:indptr[j+1]]
    sorted_out[j] = out_slice[np.argsort(weight_slice)]
```

With a simple made up example:

```
>>> graph = sps.rand(5, 5, density=0.2, format='csr')
>>> graph.toarray()
array([[ 0.88968871,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.80773932,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.8921645 ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.18552664,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.22945956]])
>>> non_empty_rows
array([0, 1, 3, 4], dtype=int64)
>>> sorted_out
{0: array([3, 0]), 1: array([2]), 3: array([0]), 4: array([4])}
```

Comment: Thank you. It looks like this effectively stores the graph twice however.  Once in graph and once in sorted_out.  Is that the idea?

Comment: You want to know your weights, and their sorting order without sorting, so you are going to need 2 values per vertex: the weight, and the order in the sorted list. So yes. You could have a single dictionary that stored the same amount of data, but you would then miss all the cool things you can do with a graph in matrix format, but it all depends in what you are after.

Comment: OK that makes sense but is a shame.